# using one form for CRUD operations against a table with key defined as AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Java/Spring/Hibernate/CXF/MySQL SOAP webservice and corresponding web Spring MVC client.

Table in back of webservice has id set to AUTO INCREMENT as usual.

Entity POJO mapped to table has

```
@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
@XmlElement(name="id")
private long id;
```

Model POJO in webclient has

```
private long id;
```

updateInsert.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c"      uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt"    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="joda"   uri="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form"   uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<style>
.error {
    color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
<head>
  <title>Form Template Insert Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Form Template Insert page</h1>
  <form:form modelAttribute="formTemplateInsertUpdateForm" method="post">
 <!--   <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />  -->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><form:label  path="id"> id: </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input  path="id" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="id" cssClass="error" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><form:label  path="name"> name: </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input  path="name" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><form:label  path="revision"> revision: </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input  path="revision" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="revision" cssClass="error" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><form:label  path="form"> form: </form:label></td>
        <td><form:input  path="form" /></td>
        <td><form:errors path="form" cssClass="error" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Insert" /></td>

            <input value="Insert" name="insert" type="submit" id="btnInsert" class="submit_button">
            <input value="Update" name="update" type="submit" id="btnUpdate" class="submit_button">
            <input value="Delete" name="delete" type="submit" id="btnDelete" class="submit_button">
            <input value="Cancel" name="cancel" type="submit" id="btnCancel" class="submit_button">


      </tr>
    </table>
  </form:form>
  <br><strong><c:out value="${aMsg}" /></strong><br>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to use one Model for inserting, updating, or deleting an entity Java instance/row of table.

The id of the row is only known **after** the object is commited/flushed as in this fragment from the DaoImpl:

```
public FormTemplate insert( FormTemplate formTemplate)
{
    logger.debug("entering");

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(formTemplate);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    logger.debug("exiting ");

    return formTemplate;
}
```

The Problem: when insertUpdate.jsp is first opened, id has a default value of 0. So insertion into table fails of course because a value for id was specified.

Can I simply set type of id in Model POJO to Long instead of long and set default to null? That sounds suspiciously easy.

Or must I have a separate Insert and UpdateDelete Model POJOs and corresponding jsps, the latter having an id field and the former not?

Larger question: is it possible for a controller's get-method to control the visibility of fields defined in the jsp? Example: calling myWebClient/formTemplate/insert opens insertUpdate.jsp but the id field is not displayed?

TIA,

Still-learning Stev

Answer (score 0):

`long` is a primitive and can never be `null`. Try the `Long` class.